# My request @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/home", "/index"})

Tags: spring-mvc

Learning Spring. My request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/home", "/index"})
```

Application is working only working with "/"
When I pass `"/home"`, `"/index"`, I am getting error **404 error** - 
The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Any help please

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow! please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask);  if you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem;  also, remember to include a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve);  people will be glad to help.

Comment: solved. Issue was with configuration